# phonegap run android not working and no error message

Tags: android, cordova

I had worked with Phonegap for a period of time and it workd good but yesterday I got stuck in a problem with installing the app on my device using command line:

```
\>>phonegap run android  
it return
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run android'
and no error message
```

But nothing happened the app as it does not get installed in my device nor open the emulator.

I try to create new project, update Phonegap, update android platform, update SDK and uninstall the phonegap and re-install it but nothing changed.

Comment: Where is the error log?

Comment: it jest no error and complete Successfully but the phonegap does not install the app to my devise for some reason i do not know !!

Comment: i suspect that was a permission issue, pls check i have posted an answer

Comment: Any good idea is open Android SDK Manager. Go to Tools/Manage AVDs menu.
See if the AVDs that a correct configuration.
If see "?" is any problem.

Answer (score 10):

I was having the exact same problem. Adding this line to the config.xml file solved it for me:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
```

I found this solution after running it as a Cordova command `cordova run android` instead of a Phonegap command. The Cordova command gave the error below error:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library C:\Users\ecarriger\Desktop\test\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

Changing the minSdkVersion to 10 in the Android manifest that the error pointed to didn't work because the run process overwrites it.

Comment: value = 10, or in my case, value = 14. I found that the --verbose flag on the build gives the minimum value required.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me also and I was going nuts for last couple of days trying to figure out and it finally worked. Here is what I did to make it work:

1. Install Apache Ant  (see http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)
2. Under Android SDK Manager, scroll to the bottom and look for Emulator Accelerator under Extras folder (It was specifically called Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator on my machine).

Once installed, I restarted the command window (Administrator mode) and now it worked.

You may also try to type cordova run android which is where I saw the Apache Ant server error.

Answer (score 1):

With `phonegap run android --verbose` you can get more info.
I encountered the same problem. Maybe not the same error.

**Command:** `phonegap run android --verbose`

> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>
> You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

When I ran the command below I saw another error.

**Command:** `cordova build android --release`

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':processReleaseManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library C:\Users\Username....\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\release\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage

Changing the minSdkVersion in the config.xml to 14 worked. It is the same solution as 3than's solution. Only the number is different.

```xml
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
```

Comment: run --verbose gave me the neccessary hints. In my case (iOS target) the ios-deploy npm package wasn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, apk not installed on the device with `cordova run android` command, i did some research and found a solution.

Open a new terminal window and navigate to your outputs /apk folder

for me it is `/NetBeansProjects/CordovaProjects/JQT/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk$`

then run the command `adb install -r android-debug.apk`

it gave the following message

```
4927 KB/s (1842130 bytes in 0.365s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
Success
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
```

the apk was successfully installed.
you can try the same

Answer (score 0):

- installing ant using command

  brew install ant
- running the following command in /platforms/android/

  android update project --name <project_name> --target <target> --path <path>

solved the problem for me.