# Cordova build android not working

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, phonegap

Phonegap has failed to build my android app.

I have followed this tutorial to setup android https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/#android-dev-env

After this process, I run android and the Android SDK Manager is launched, Instead I get this in CMD.

```
C:\Users\Jamie>android
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

Now I cannot build my phonegap android apps.

Phonegap now throws this and exits with 1,

```
[INF] [shellscript] [phonegap] executing '''cordova build android'''...
[INF] [shellscript] Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed
. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

What I am surprised about is that I set ANDROID_HOME  in the link above above
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818635/phonegap-run-android-not-working-and-no-error-message) has not worked for me

Comment: type "echo %ANDROID_HOME%" in command prompt and check whether you are getting the android home path properly

Comment: C:\Users\User>%ANDROID_HOME%
'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' is not recognized as an internal or ex
ternal command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: type "echo %ANDROID_HOME%" not just %ANDROID_HOME%

Comment: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: have you installed cordova globally using -g option?

Comment: yes, I did. Typing cordova in CMD lists all the OPTIONS

Comment: The command output actually tells you what to do. "For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio. For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat". Have you tried this? What happened?